# Dependant object as parameter to dependency in Autofac

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

In broader terms what I am trying to achieve with Autofac is to pass the dependant (a.k.a. parent) object to its dependencies.

For example:

```
interface IDependency {}

class Dependant
{
    IDependency Dependency { get; set; }
}

class ConcreteDependency : IDependency
{
    ConcreteDependency(Dependant dependant) { /* ... */ }
}
```

I am hoping this could work, because `Dependant` breaks the dependency loop using property injection (meaning you *can* create an instance of `Dependant`, *before* having to resolve `IDependency`). Whilst, if both classes used ctor-injection this wouldn't be possible.

Specifically, I am trying to *inject* the current ASP.NET MVC controller instance to one of its dependencies.

Take a look at:

```
public abstract class ApplicationController : Controller
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set;}
}

public class SomeController : ApplicationController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection formData)
    {
        // something fails...
        this.Logger.Log("Something has failed.");
    }
}

public interface ILogger
{
    public void Log(string message);
}

public class TempDataLogger : ILogger
{
    private ControllerBase controller;

    public NullLogger(ControllerBase controller)
    {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public void Log(string message)
    {
        this.controller.TempData["Log"] = message;
    }
}
```

In plain English the above code uses `TempData` as a way of "logging" messages (maybe to print it out in a nice way in view-layout or something...).

Simple enough all controllers are registered in Autofac:

```
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly)
       .PropertiesAutowired(); // not strictly necessary
```

But then, how can I tweak the `ILogger` registration below to make it work?

```
builder.RegisterType<TempDataLogger>()
       .As<ILogger>()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

Is this even possible in Autofac?

Thank you.

Comment: for your use case why don't you do this, Constructor inject ILogger to the controller , then write a extension method  on ILogger which print nice way or what ever you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is interested, the solution below is the closest I was able to get so far:

```
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly)
       .PropertiesAutowired() // not strictly necessary
       .OnActivating(e => ((ApplicationController)e.Instance).Logger = new TempDataLogger((ApplicationController)e.Instance));
```

... and therefore, no need to;

```
builder.RegisterType<TempDataLogger>()
       .As<ILogger>()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```